# Understanding nested arrow functions ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
    let result
    console.groupCollapsed("dispatching", action.type)
    console.log('prev state', store.getState())
    console.log('action', action)
    result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    console.groupEnd()
    return result
}

const store = applyMiddleware(logger)(createStore)(
    combineReducers({ colors, sort })
)
```

Would you please explain the above function with multiple arrows?

Comment: Function returning function returning function.

Comment: use babeljs repl if you can't read ES6

Comment: Want to understand arrow functions in ES6. - @Jaromanda X

Comment: Yes. But if you understand es5 but not that fluent in es6 babel can help you learn

Comment: Will just add the link for Babel to this which is https://babeljs.io/ - perfect for seeing what the older equivalent of the new JS is - thanks @JaromandaX

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The code below:

```
const logger = store => next => action => { return 'something'; }
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
const logger = function(store) { 
    return function(next) {
        return function(action) {
            return 'something';
        }
    }
}
```

And it can be called like below:

```
var something = logger(store)(next)(action);
```